# Is this a mistake in the Android API or am I just misunderstanding definitions?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the Fragment API there is a method called [onHiddenChanged(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged%28boolean%29) that, and I'm wondering if there is a mistake in how the parameter is defined. It says:

> *hidden*        True if the fragment is now hidden, false if it is not visible.

Either hidden and invisible don't share the same definition and the boolean is creating a relationship between the two, or the wording is incorrect.  I think it is the latter. If it is I should be reporting to android, is anyone else reading this as I am? Or is there an interpretation of this that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

[According to this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isHidden%28%29) `hidden` property is orthogonal to visibility. `Fragment` could be hidden/shown and not started/started

> to be visible to the user, a fragment must be both started and not hidden.

So, fragment could be not hidden, but still invisible.

Comment: +1 because this the answer because it comes pretty close to answering the question, but there still remains what true and false actually mean. There are two different states that are presumably unrelated to each other that are being tied together in this boolean. What happens when a fragment is hidden and not visible? Either true or false is an acceptable answer, which destroys the point of the method. Thanks for your continued efforts.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53178

> "hidden   True if the fragment is now hidden, false if it is not
>   visible."
>
> Isn't "now hidden" the same as "not visible" ?
>
> Seems it should read "...false if it is NOW visible."

Comment: The problem is it seems to be convoluting the two "hidden" and "visible" (and there is a isVisible() method); if hidden and invisible have two distinct definitions it should be "True if the fragment is now hidden, false if it is now not hidden."